# Python Arpabet phonetic transcription

Tags: python

Is there a library in python that can convert words (mainly names) to Arpabet phonetic transcription?

BARBELS -> B AA1 R B AH0 L Z

BARBEQUE -> B AA1 R B IH0 K Y UW2

BARBEQUED -> B AA1 R B IH0 K Y UW2 D

BARBEQUEING -> B AA1 R B IH0 K Y UW2 IH0 NG

BARBEQUES -> B AA1 R B IH0 K Y UW2 Z

Comment: It doesn't have Arpabet, but if you're generally looking for sound analysis, you might take a look at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fuzzy/

Answer (score 16):

What you want is variously called "letter to sound" or "grapheme to phoneme" engine.  There are a few around, including one in every text-to-speech system.

I usually deal with non-US accents, for which I use [espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/).  It doesn't output arpabet directly (which is restricted to US sounds anyway), but you can coax it to attempt an American accent, and convert from IPA to arpabet later.

```
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> print check_output(["espeak", "-q", "--ipa",
                        '-v', 'en-us',
                        'hello  world']).decode('utf-8')
həlˈoʊ wˈɜːld
```

You can use `-x` rather than `--ipa` for espeak's own phone representation (it's ascii):

```
>>> check_output(["espeak", "-q", "-x", '-v', 'en-us', 'hello world'])
h@l'oU w'3:ld
```

Converting to arpabet isn't quite as simple as a character look-up though; for example "tʃ" should be converted to "CH", not the "T SH" that a greedy conversion would give you (except, that is, in odd cases like "swˈɛtʃɑːp" for "sweatshop").

Comment: This looks like the most relevant answer OP's question, but can you please elaborate on how to use Python to use espeak. I downloaded 'espeak-1.48.04-source', but it has a bunch of folders, and not sure how to apply your above Python code, I understand it's a question answered long time ago, so much appreciated if you can help.

Comment: @vrplumber's answer has (at this writing) the fewest votes, but his `listener` project handles the conversion from espeak output to ARPAbet.

Answer (score 15):

Using [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/documentation) with the `cmudict` corpus installed:

```
arpabet = nltk.corpus.cmudict.dict()
for word in ('barbels', 'barbeque', 'barbequed', 'barbequeing', 'barbeques'):
    print(arpabet[word])
```

yields

```
[['B', 'AA1', 'R', 'B', 'AH0', 'L', 'Z']]
[['B', 'AA1', 'R', 'B', 'IH0', 'K', 'Y', 'UW2']]
[['B', 'AA1', 'R', 'B', 'IH0', 'K', 'Y', 'UW2', 'D']]
[['B', 'AA1', 'R', 'B', 'IH0', 'K', 'Y', 'UW2', 'IH0', 'NG']]
[['B', 'AA1', 'R', 'B', 'IH0', 'K', 'Y', 'UW2', 'Z']]
```

---

To install the `cmudict` corpus in the python interpreter type:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
Use GUI to install 
corpora>cmudict
```

Comment: That's also useful, but it doesn't work for words outside this dictionary, is there a way to find the arpabet for any string? or at least some way to syllabify the string and look for syllables in the dictionary?

Comment: Such a thing might exist, but I don't know about it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a tiny utility from my listener project to do this. It uses espeak under the covers (to generate IPA), then uses a mapping extracted from the CMU dictionary to produce the set of ARPABet mappings that could match the IPA generated, for instance:

```
$ listener-arpa 
we are testing
we
        W IY
are
        ER
        AA
testing
        T EH S T IH NG
```

That produces exact-matches on the CMU dictionary about 45% of the time (I got around 36% using the documented correspondence in CMU/Wikipedia) while producing ~3 matches per word (on average). That said, we see a "close match" about 99% of the time, that is, while we might not precisely match the hand-marked-up word every time, we are generally off by only a few phonemes.

```
$ sudo apt-get install espeak
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/mcfletch/listener.git#egg=listener
```

Answer (score 5):

Get the [cmu pronouncing dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict) and then you can use [nltk](http://nltk.org/) to get the associated
arpabet phonetic transcription for any word from that dictionary itself like this

```
>>> entries = nltk.corpus.cmudict.entries()
>>> len(entries)
127012
>>> for entry in entries[39943:39951]:
...     print entry
...
('fir', ['F', 'ER1'])
('fire', ['F', 'AY1', 'ER0'])
('fire', ['F', 'AY1', 'R'])
('firearm', ['F', 'AY1', 'ER0', 'AA2', 'R', 'M'])
('firearm', ['F', 'AY1', 'R', 'AA2', 'R', 'M'])
('firearms', ['F', 'AY1', 'ER0', 'AA2', 'R', 'M', 'Z'])
('firearms', ['F', 'AY1', 'R', 'AA2', 'R', 'M', 'Z'])
('fireball', ['F', 'AY1', 'ER0', 'B', 'AO2', 'L'])
```

Comment: that's useful, but I mainly need it to pronounce words that are not on the list of entries, at least I get a list of syllables together with their transcription, so that I can use these syllables in new words...