# How can I get a rough ARPAbet-like pronunciation from an aribtrary word that's not in the CMU Pronunciation Dictionary?

Tags: python, nlp

I'm working on a python-based NLP project, finding soundalikes for a large set of words.

The project requires me to derive rough pronunciations of the words in my set. I care mostly about consonant sounds. I *would* use the CMU pronunciation dictionary, but not all the words I'm processing are in their dictionary. DoubleMetaphone gives a decent approximation of the consonant sounds, but it's optimized for names, and it's very rough on certain sounds I'd like to capture (e.g. initial "w"). I've considered adapting the DoubleMetaphone algorithm, but it's a daunting thought.

My question: **Is there any existing project out there that does pronunciation analysis of words, beyond Soundex/Metaphone/NYSIIS/MRA?** Something that uses the same ARPAbet as CMU would be splendid.

Comment: This should do exactly what you want http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lextool.html

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, that's a great resource. Care to add it as an answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911028/python-arpabet-phonetic-transcription?

Comment: I put a link there.